# Python3 ModuleNotFoundError when importing from a parent directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, virtualenv

I have a python virtualvenv in a directory and inside it, I have created a scrapy project using startproject command line.

My directory structure:

```
root
 | settings.py
 | env (virtual env)
 | requirements.txt (has scrapy, splash and other modules)
 | __init__.py
 |
 | shared (shared code)
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | helper.py
 |
 | scrapy_project
 |  | scrapy.cfg
 |  | WebCrawler
 |  |  | __init__.py
 |  |  | settings.py
 |  |  | items.py
 |  |  | spiders
 |  |  |  | SplashSpider.py
```

When I want to run the `scrapy_project` spider I do `cd scrapy_project` and then `scrapy crawl splash_spider` but the problem is that inside my `SplashSpider.py` I need to import some code from `shared` module in the root directory.

I tried importing the `helper.py` using `from shared import helper` but I get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shared'`

I'm trying to have multiple scrapy projects under the root directory and use the `shared` module in each project's spiders. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: There are a few different ways to make this work. I would checkout this extensive SO answer - https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/9638991 - and the Python docs - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path.